# Upgraded GAE App to Java 8

Tags: google-app-engine

Under Versions tab it shows that I am running Java8
But at the top of the page it shows:

Your app is temporarily whitelisted to support Java 7.

What does this mean ? Am I running on a Java 8 or Java 7 compatibility stack ?
I have upgraded code to use Java 8 classes ... and the code is working correctly.

Comment: It's probably just a notice. Do you have any older app version that used Java7? We've seen that notice when we had older versions deployed with Java7.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had the notice since you had Java 7 in the past.

You can see how to migrate [in here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8), so check your configuration to see if you successfully migrated to Java 8.

You can also check your configuration in Cloud Platform, going to App Engine -> Versions, and clicking in View, in the Config column.

If you didn't successfully migrate to Java 8, do so, because Java 7 runtime will be [shut down entirely on January 16, 2019.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7)

Comment: The content from the Config column is attached: runtime: java8
api_version: '1.0'
env: standard
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F1
inbound_services:
  - mail
  - warmup
handlers:
  - url: "(/_ah/mail/.*\\.txt)"
    login: admin
    application_readable: false
    static_files: "__static__\\1"
    require_matching_file: true
    upload: __NOT_USED__
  - url: "(/cron/.*\\.txt)"
    login: admin
    application_readable: false
    static_files: "__static__\\1"
    require_matching_file: true
    upload: __NOT_USED__
     ..

Comment: If you have `runtime` as Java8, you properly configured your application as I linked in my first link, and you don't have any errors whatsoever, you are running in Java 8, and you got the message since you were running Java 7 on the past.